# Solving the sum of a sequence to find term n

Tags: sequences-and-series

For the function defined by $S_n = n^2 - 3n$ for $n = 1, 2, 3, ...$ find Tn and hence show that this series is arithmetic.

I understand that the function shown is the sum to $n$ terms, but how do i find an equation for term $n$ from this without first proving it as an AP (so that later I can "hence" prove it is an  AP)?

Thankyou in advance!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$T_m=S_m-S_{m-1}=m^2-3m-\{(m-1)^2-3(m-1)\}=m^2-(m-1)^2-3\{m-(m-1)\}=\cdots$$

Show that $\displaystyle T_r-T_{r-1}$ is independent of $r,$ hence constant